Find the range of $2^{\cos^{-1}\sin\left(x+\frac\pi3\right)}+\frac{\sqrt{1-2\cos x}}2$

Find the range of $$2^{\cos^{-1}\sin\left(x+\frac\pi3\right)}+\frac{\sqrt{1-2\cos x}}2.$$

My approach is s follow as $\sin\left(x+\frac\pi3\right)$ and $\frac{\sqrt{1-2\cos x}}2$ are periodic function hence we need to focus on $[0,\pi]$ but because of phase difference of $\frac{\pi}{3}$ in  the sine graph I am facing difficulty.

Why $[0,\pi]$ and not $[0,2\pi]$?

Might be useful: $\sin t=\cos(\frac\pi2-t)$

Don't you think that the first term is a red herring ?

This function isn't defined at $x=0$ (for example). Maybe you could first find where it is defined.

Let's focus on only $x\in[0,2\pi]$ due to the periodicity of the function. And,
$$f(x)=2^{\cos^{-1}\sin\left(x+\frac\pi3\right)}+\frac{\sqrt{1-2\cos x}}2\tag{1}$$
Since $1-2\cos x\ge0$, $\frac{\pi}3\le x\le\frac{5\pi}3$ or $x\in\left[\frac{\pi}3,\frac{5\pi}3\right]$ is the domain of the function $f(x)$.
Now, consider
$$g(x)=\cos^{-1}\sin\left(x+\frac\pi3\right)=\cos^{-1}\sin\left(\frac\pi2+x-\frac\pi6\right)=\begin{cases}x-\frac\pi6\qquad\text{for}~\frac\pi6\le x\le\frac{7\pi}6\\2\pi-x+\frac{\pi}6\qquad\text{for}~\frac{7\pi}6\le x\le\frac{13\pi}6\end{cases}$$
Since a smaller value of $x$ gives the larger value of $\cos x$ and a smaller value of $(1-\cos x)$ and $(x-\frac\pi6)$ is linearly increasing, the minimum value of $f(x)$ occurs at $x=\frac\pi3$ in its domain (because at another end, $g\left(\frac{5\pi}3\right)=\frac\pi2>\frac\pi6$).
So,
$$f_{\text{min}}=2^{\frac\pi6}=1.43753\ldots$$
Since $g(x)$ increases linearly up to $x=\frac{7\pi}6$ (and then decreases linearly) and $\cos x$ is negative, the maximum value of $f(x)$ occurs at $x=\frac{7\pi}6$ in its domain.
So,
$$f_{\text{max}}=2^\pi+\frac{\sqrt{1+2\cos\left(\frac\pi6\right)}}{2}=2^\pi+\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt3}}{2}=9.65142\ldots$$
Hence, the range of the function $f(x)$ is
$$\left[2^{\frac\pi6},2^\pi+\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt3}}{2}\right]=\left[1.43753\ldots,9.65142\ldots\right]$$
I hope this helps!

Bonus:
For visualization, see the graph below. The green colour represents $g(x)$, the blue one represents $2^{g(x)}$, and the red one (lower/round) represents $\frac{\sqrt{1-2\cos x}}2$. The remaining red one (higher curve) represents $f(x)$, which is the sum of the blue one and the red (lower) one. Clearly, $y=f(x)=r\in\left[2^{\frac\pi6},2^{\frac\pi2}\right)$ has unique real solution in $[0,2\pi]$.

